# Get total count of last seven days for top 5 countries of all time

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot-table

I have a table called `events` which looks like this:

```
 id |    date    | country |  event | count
--------------------------------------------- 
 1  | 2018-03-16 |   RS    | views  | 33577
 2  | 2018-03-21 |   US    | plays  | 232712
 3  | 2018-03-14 |   AR    | clicks | 469159
 4  | 2018-03-18 |   US    | plays  | 415732
 5  | 2018-03-26 |   US    | views  | 442159
 6  | 2018-03-22 |   BA    | plays  | 181610
 7  | 2018-03-21 |   UK    | plays  | 57899
 8  | 2018-03-17 |   CZ    | views  | 64605
 9  | 2018-03-17 |   BA    | plays  | 375444
 10 | 2018-03-22 |   US    | plays  | 148073
 11 | 2018-03-23 |   BA    | views  | 181644
 12 | 2018-03-22 |   CZ    | clicks | 411953
 13 | 2018-03-15 |   AR    | views  | 329597
 14 | 2018-03-18 |   BA    | clicks | 480834
 15 | 2018-03-17 |   CZ    | plays  | 279060
 16 | 2018-03-19 |   MN    | views  | 611975
 17 | 2018-03-26 |   MN    | clicks | 227115
 18 | 2018-03-24 |   BA    | plays  | 176248
 19 | 2018-03-14 |   UK    | views  | 288072
 20 | 2018-03-18 |   UK    | plays  | 598980
```

I need to get sum of counts of each event for the last seven days of the top 5 countries of all times.
Currently, I have a query that does that:

```
SELECT
    `c`.`country`,
    `event`,
    SUM(`count`) AS `total`
FROM
    `eem_events` `a`
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        `country`
    FROM
        `eem_events` `b`
    GROUP BY
        `country`
    ORDER BY
        SUM(`count`)
    DESC
LIMIT 5
) AS `c`
WHERE
    `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY
    `c`.`country`,
    `event`
```

This query returns this:

```
 country | event  | count 
-----------------------------
   AR    | views  | 43084323
   AR    | plays  | 46487773
   AR    | clicks | 44581794
   BA    | views  | 43084323
   BA    | plays  | 46487773
   BA    | clicks | 44581794
   DE    | views  | 43084323
   DE    | plays  | 46487773
   DE    | clicks | 44581794
   MN    | views  | 43084323
   MN    | plays  | 46487773
   MN    | clicks | 44581794
   UK    | views  | 43084323
   UK    | plays  | 46487773
   UK    | clicks | 44581794
```

What I would like to get is following:

```
 country |   views   |   plays   |  clicks   
-----------------------------------------------
   AR    | 43084323  | 46487773  | 44581794
   BA    | 43084323  | 46487773  | 44581794
   DE    | 43084323  | 46487773  | 44581794
   MN    | 43084323  | 46487773  | 44581794
   UK    | 43084323  | 46487773  | 44581794
```

I am trying to do this for like 12 hours now and I don't have any more ideas. You can see that for views, plays and clicks there are same values. Could you please help me with refactoring my SQL query to get this result?

I am using MySQL / MariaDB.

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza MySQL / MariaDB

Comment: Im guessing the inner query with `limit 5`  is already working and returning the country with more clicks?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yeah, that query is working as it should

Comment: Your current query should return an error message, the `ON` is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need add conditional `SUM()`

```
SELECT
    `c`.`country`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'views'  THEN `count` ELSE 0 END) AS `views`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'plays'  THEN `count` ELSE 0 END) AS `plays`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'clicks' THEN `count` ELSE 0 END) AS `clicks`
FROM
    `eem_events` `a`
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT    `country`
    FROM      `eem_events` `b`
    GROUP BY  `country`
    ORDER BY   SUM(`count`) DESC
    LIMIT 5
) AS `c`
  ON `a`.`country` = `c`.`country`
WHERE
    `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY
    `c`.`country`
```

Comment: It is not working, it returns same count of views for every country.

Comment: Yes I see that in your question just now ... You didnt add the `ON` condition for the `JOIN`. give me a min.

Comment: please check again

Comment: Wow, that crappy MySQL actually allows omitting the ON in a join without a syntax error?

Comment: @dnoeth I guess so. :/

Comment: I would like to know the reason, another *"bad for performance when the DBMS checks it"* or *"should be handled by the middle layer"*? :-)